# Difference between char* [number] and char (*)[number] in type declaration

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, types

What's the difference between the two? I know the difference between char* (char pointer) and char[] (char array). But I'm not sure the difference between `char* [3]` and `char (*)[3]`. I would think both name a pointer to a char array with 3 elements, but C++ makes some destinction between the two. I haven't found any useful information about the two declarations on the internet.

Comment: I'd suggest this for one way of reading declarations: http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html

Comment: this is C and as far as I know char* a and char *a does not make a difference in C.

Comment: It applies pretty well to C++ and it definitely applies to this case when you put variable names in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Difference between char* [number] and char (*)[number] in type declaration

`char* [number]` is an array of pointers to char.

`char (*)[number]` is a pointer to an array of char.

Some bonus examples:

`char* (*)[number]` is a pointer to an array of pointers to char.

`char* (*)()` is a pointer to a function that returns a pointer to char.

`char* (*[number])()` is an array of pointers to functions that return a pointer to char.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
char* [3]
```

is array type that has `3` elements of the type `char *`.

This

```
char (*)[3]
```

is pointer type that points to array of the type `char [3]`.

Here is a demonstrative program. In this program instead of the type char *[3] I will use the type `const char *[3]` because in C++ string literals (that are used in the program as initializers) have types of constant character arrays.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 3;
    const char * a[N] = { "Hello", "everybody", "here" };

    char s[N] = { '1', '2', '3' };
    char ( *p )[N] = &s;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << a[i] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << ( *p )[i] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello everybody here 
1 2 3
```

In the program there is used an array of the type `const char *[3]`

```
    const char * a[N] = { "Hello", "everybody", "here" };
```

and a pointer of the type `char ( * )[3]` that is initialized by the address of an array of the type `char[3]`

```
    char s[N] = { '1', '2', '3' };
    char ( *p )[N] = &s;
```